# Spring Boot Application on Springfox for swagger-ui PUT always "Invalid CORS Request"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cors, swagger-ui

I've got a Spring Boot Application based in 1.5.3.RELEASE that is leveraging springfox-swagger2 at 2.6.1 and springfox-swagger-ui at 2.6.1.

For most of the API, stuff is just fine. GETs work. POSTs work. PUTs always error at the swagger-ui.html `Invalid CORS request` I can reproduce the problem localhost with a request like...

```
$ curl -i -X PUT 'http://localhost.mycompany.com:8080/mom/749f4f1f-0769-488d-9776-17fc3927cfc6/description?description=WangoTango' \
> -H 'Origin: http://example.com' \
> -H 'Cookie: a.token_key=redacted' \
> -H 'accept: application/json'
HTTP/1.1 403
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 20
Date: Sat, 11 Nov 2023 01:42:01 GMT

Invalid CORS request
```

My application is configured per https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/integrations/cors.html with a CorsConfigurationSource

```
/**
 * CORS Configuration lifted from https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/integrations/cors.html;
 * configure to allow all origins, all methods.
 */
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
  }
```

In the Controller..the endpoint too is configured with the extraoridinarly permissive CrossOrigin annotation...

```
  @RequestMapping(
      method = RequestMethod.PUT,
      path = "/mom/{verId:.+}/description",
      produces = {"application/json"})
  @CrossOrigin
  @ApiOperation(value = "Set the description")
  @ApiResponses(value = {
          @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = MBom.class),
          @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request", response = String.class),
          @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Error", response = String.class)})
  public ResponseEntity<?> setDescription(
      @PathVariable("verId") String verId,
      @RequestParam("description") String description) {
...
```

What is the magic configuration in a Spring Boot 1.5.3.RELEASE Application to get the PUT endpoints working with CORS? I've had no success with any of the prior answers to this on StackOverflow.

Comment: Do you have a spring security filter chain configuration? Also your spring boot version is quite outdated and probably does not work properly together  with current spring-security versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass explicit method names like `PUT`, `POST` instead of `*` in `CorsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods`

Update to this:

```
configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE"));
```

See if this works.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    // the below three lines will add the relevant CORS response headers
    configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new 
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```